# How to know how many main Collections you have in in Firestore Database?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The question is simple ( I want to count the collections inside the Firestore which are in the first row list) as shown in the pic below:

[image]

As you saw in the picture I have 3 collections in the list... so what about if I have a big list or as you know this list might has more and more collections in the future.

**So, Ho to get them counted programmatically? **

WHY ??
The answer is:
I want to use the count inside an array that will determine the number of cells inside the UICollectionView because I want to show the products of each collection in Firestore inside the Reusable cells

All methods which are in google search are talking about how to count the documents not about the main collection count !!

Comment: No, if you want to know how many collections in your FirestoreData what you will do?
please re read my question again bro

Comment: @Let.Simoo , do you need to count the starting collections like the first column of the fireStore DB, Or  you need to count the whole number of collections in your DB including the subCollection going down the hierarchy.

Comment: Dear @Coder Thank you for your comment... Yes exactly I want to to count the starting collections in the first column of the FireStore DB ( without ) the subCollection,

Comment: "The question is clear"  No, it's not.  The following statement doesn't make sense.  "I want to get the count number of my collections inside the Firestore"  Collections?  What do you mean by that?  You are accessing two or more databases?  Or you want to know the number of records in relation to a single database?

Comment: The problem here is the structure. You would not typically want to store that data at the Firestore root level. You would typically store data you want to use in a UICollectionView as documents within a collection. So for example, a Users collection would have documents with documentId's being the users UID. Within each users document, there may have a collection of that users pets, for example, which each pet being a document within the child pets_collection. Etc etc. So the structure would be *firestore_root/users_collection/user_id/pets_collection/pet_id* etc.

Comment: Collections are not meant to be dynamically named.  You should instead consider putting your dynamic data in documents that can be queried, then use subcollection under that for further organization if needed.

Comment: This question should re open @ElTomato

Comment: Subject edited, and improved the question with a screenshot and more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API in the Firebase SDKs for iterating root collections or subcollections of a document, which means you have to know the name of the collection to perform any queries. Only in Node.js server SDK you can use the `listCollections()` to get the desired result.
As an alternate, you can make a separate collection `allCollections` and then whenever you create new root collection, add one document with same name in `allCollections` and then you can count from that new collection.

Comment: Appreciate your smart idea, yes this will work with me definitely !!... Thank you my friend you are the only one who understood what  I want exactly!... can you suggest an edit to the title of my question please please?